# Autosave on PHP+mysql every few minutes

Tags: php, mysql, ajax

I have a site (php) with a text editor that I want to be saved automatically every few minutes (on mysql) and I wanted to consult with you about this.

(You may know this behavior from the Google Docs platform.)

Won't it kill my DB if I'll call it again and again?
Is their a known approach for this type of feature?
Does it matter if I save every minute or every type that the user is doing?

Any tips that can help me start with this feature?

Comment: U could check the previous saved input with the current to avoid saving non-modified data

Comment: Why does it need to be stored in a DB?

Comment: So people can resume their work when there browser crashes or something i presume? :)

Comment: what you are suggesting is a page that does a post every view minutes. This is easy. Even with 60 users all at once, saving every minute, you'd only have 60 querys a minute, which is only a fraction of what a simple database can handle. Obviously hardware etc is a factor, but there is no reason to even consider this heavy usage. Consider adding a counter to the save-call, so you don't override newer saves.

Comment: @Nanne, thanks for your answer. Do you know how/where can I test the max amount of queries per minute the my db can handle? 60 sounds like a lot to me, but how do you know this is considered a "fraction"? :)

Comment: It is completely dependend on your hardware. But set up a lamp/wamp/mamp stack, and just test it on your local machine.

Answer (score 0):

It depends on your server and the amount of data saved to mysql, tell us more why do you want to save text editor data to database, i`m pretty sure there`s a better way to do this.

If you want to save data for users, you should use local storage, you can do it using JQuery plugins:

Ex:
http://www.jstorage.info/

Comment: This is a comment, not an answer. I appreciate that you have diminished reputation so you can't comment but this answer won't help.

Comment: I need to save the data on the DB because I want my users to be able to restore it (no matter what device they are using).